# Solving a Wave Equation using Fourier Series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Here is my problem (made by the teacher, using in class the book Partial Differential Equations, by Walter Strauss):

Solve the following wave equation on the half-line

- $U_{tt}$ - $c^2$$U_{xx}$ = $0$, $x>0, t>0$
- $U(x,0)$ = $U_t$$(x,0)$ = $1$, $x>0$
- $U(0,t)$ = $0$, $t \ge 0$

And my math skills are a little rusty, so please correct me and tell me where I need to practice if I make a mistake.

What troubles me in solving the equation is the value of the boundary condition $1$ - I can't figure out a way to find eigensolutions because of it, and that there's only one initial condition for x. Here is the work I have now:

My solution will have the form:

$U(x,t) = X(x) * T(t)$

Separating the values and moving X, T around gets us to:

$\frac{T''(t)}{c^2T(t)} = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = -\lambda$

Which gives us two characteristic equations:

- $X''(x) + \lambda X(x) = 0$
- $T''(t) + c^2\lambda T(t) = 0$

Staring with X, say $\lambda = -\beta^2 < 0$. Then:

$X(x) = Ae^{\beta x} + Be^{-\beta x}$

$X(0) = A + B = 0$, so $A = -B$ and $X(x) = A(e^{\beta x} - e^{-\beta x})$

But there's not a second condition, so I can't go any further and determine A.

Say $\lambda = 0$. Then:

$X(x) = A + Bx$, so $X(0) = A = 0$, and $X(x) = Bx$, but without a second condition, I can't determine B.

Say $\lambda = \beta^2 > 0$. Then:

$X(x) = Acos(\beta x) + Bsin(\beta x)$, so $X(0) = A = 0,$ and $X(x) = Bsin(\beta x)$, but no further condition to solve for B.

Now for the characteristic equation for T:

Say $c^2 \lambda = -\beta^2 < 0$. Then after solving the system of linear equations, you eventually get to the solution of:

$T(t) = \frac{\beta - 1}{2\beta}e^{\beta t} + \frac{1 -\beta}{2\beta}e^{\beta t}$

If $c^2 \lambda = 0$ we get the trivial solution, but if $c^2 \lambda = \beta^2 > 0$:

$T(t) = cos(\beta t) + \frac{1}{\beta}sin(\beta t)$

As in, I don't get a system of eigensolutions like I am hoping for and don't know what to do next...how do I keep moving with this problem?

Comment: are you sure you copied right? don't these initial conditions contradict each other: $U(x, 0) = 1$ with $U(0, t) = 0$? What should be $U(0,0)$?

Comment: you are solving on the half-line, $x \in [0, +\infty)$, the second condition is implied, I think: $U(x, t)$ should not diverge at infinity.

Comment: I mistakenly forgot to add that the boundaries are x > 0, t > 0, which is now added in. Otherwise it is correct.

Comment: alright, since you have added the Fourier series tag, assuming this is an exercise in that, what you need to do is decompose the initial condition into the eigensolutions at $t = 0$. Only $\lambda < 0$ actually gives you solutions that don't diverge as $x \rightarrow \infty$, so use those. They are $\sin(\beta x) T(0) = \sin(\beta x)$. So take the function that is $=1$ except at $x = 0$ (where it is $0$) and expand it in a Fourier series of sines. Those then start evolving over time,each according to its corresponding $T(t)$, then you have to put them all together again.